# Javascript - Accessing static method from another static method throws ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, static, referenceerror

I have defined an helper class to create some objects.
As objects A contain Bs, I'm trying to call the createB from createA but I get a "*Uncaught ReferenceError: createB is not defined*".
JS is not my main language so please forgive me if it's something obvious ;)

Here is my code:

```
define([
  "model/A",
  "model/B",
  "model/C"
], function (A, B, C) {
  return {
    addTo: function (params, key, target, source) {
      if (params[key] !== undefined && params[key] !== null) {
        target.set(key, params[key], source);
      }
    },
    createA: function (params, source) {
      var result = new A();

      ...
      bDefs.forEach(function(bDef) {
        result.get("bs").push(this.createB(params,source));
      });
      return result;
    },
    createB: function (params, source) {

      var result = new B();
      ...

      result.get("cs").push(createC(params,source));
      return result;
    },
    createMediaType: function (params, source) {

      var result = new C();
      ...

      return result;
    }
  };
});
```

**EDIT**: reading the question again I noticed I omitted something important that could be the cause of the issue: I'm calling createB() from within a forEach. I suppose that anonymous function does not have visibility of the rest of the class. How can I pass a reference to **this** to the forEach?

Comment: It's not okay on SO to edit the question such that the edit invalidates existing answers to the question as it was, so I've removed the `this.` from the `createB` call that you added with an edit. As [algiogia said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37696799/javascript-accessing-static-method-from-another-static-method-throws-reference/37696945?noredirect=1#comment62869281_37696945), the solution in my answer also deals with the `forEach` problem. I've also updated the answer to show you how to make `forEach` work if you want to pursue using `this`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I've edited the question because it was wrong. Copying the code in SO I omitted a relevant part. In the initial version I had also mentioned I tried using "this.createB()" already. Your answer is still valid.

Comment: Even if you just posted the code incorrectly, it would be inappropriate on SO to fix it *once an answer was received that it invalidated*. However, as you note, your original question *did* have that bit at the end about `this.createB` (I missed that!), so it doesn't apply in this case. BTW, in my comment above, I meant "as jamiec said" not "as algiogia said" - doh!

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
result.get("bs").push(createB(params,source));
```

expects that there will be an in-scope identifier called `createB`. There isn't one in your code. The property keys in an object initializer do not become freestanding identifiers (thankfully).

Assuming that `createA` will be called with `this` referring to the object you've created with the initializer, you could use `this.createB` there instead. But it requires that assumption about `this`, which would need to be enforced in the code *using* your object. I give you an alternative below.

> I'm calling `createB()` from within a `forEach`. I suppose that anonymous function does not have visibility of the rest of the class.

Yes, it does. (And that's not a class.)

> How can I pass a reference to this to the `forEach`?

The second argument to `forEach` is the value to use as `this` during the callback, so:

```
bDefs.forEach(function(bDef) {
    result.get("bs").push(this.createB(params,source));
}, this);
// ^^^^
```

or alternately you can use `Function#bind`, but I wouldn't here.

If you were using ES2015 (aka "ES6"), you could use an arrow function, since arrow functions close over the `this` value of the context where they're created:

```
// Requires ES2015 ("ES6")
bDefs.forEach(bDef => {
    result.get("bs").push(this.createB(params,source));
});
```

---

You have a second option that doesn't rely on the calling code to call with the correct `this` value and doesn't require you to preserve that value within the `forEach`: You can make those functions freestanding identifiers in a private scope, and also return them as properties on the object:

```
define([
  "model/A",
  "model/B",
  "model/C"
], function (A, B, C) {
  // Note how each of these is a function declaration; that defines
  // their names as in-scope identifiers within this anonymous function
  // and the functions created within it (which close over the context of
  // the call to this anonymous function where these are created).
  function addTo(params, key, target, source) {
    if (params[key] !== undefined && params[key] !== null) {
      target.set(key, params[key], source);
    }
  }

  function createA(params, source) {
    var result = new A();

    ...
    result.get("bs").push(createB(params,source));

    return result;
  }

  function createB(params, source) {

    var result = new B();
    ...

    result.get("cs").push(createC(params,source));
    return result;
  }

  function createMediaType(params, source) {

    var result = new C();
    ...

    return result;
  }

  // Now we return the object
  return {
      addTo: addTo,
      createA: createA,
      createB: createB,
      createMediaType: createMediaType
  };
});
```

---

Side note: In ES2015 (aka "ES6") that object initializer at the end can be a bit more concise:

```
// Requires ES2015 (aka "ES6")
return {
    addTo,
    createA,
    createB,
    createMediaType
};
```

Comment: Thanks. I found the issue is the forEach (see updated question).

Comment: @algiogia if you do it the way shown in this answer, it also solves your `forEach` issue as well.

Comment: @algiogia: Is there something futher you need clarified?